# Nuxt.js run code on page load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

How do I run code when a [page](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#pages) loads with Nuxt.js?

I'd like to add a class if the browser supports touch events using `!!window.ontouchstart`.

I tried this, but `window` is undefined:

````
```
<section v-bind:class="{ touch: !!window.ontouchstart }">
   ...
</section>
```
````

Comment: Viewed 10,000 times.  One upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first add an `eventlistener` to listen to touchstart.

```
created: function(){
    document.addEventListener('touchstart',this.touchStart);
 }, 
destroyed: function() { 
    document.removeEventListener('touchstart', this.touchStart); 
 }
```

Now you can use touch touchStart method
inside Vue methods.

```
methods:{
  touchStart(e){
    this.touched=true;
  }

}
```

In html

```
<section v-bind:class="{ touch: touched}"> ... </section>
```

Also `ontouchstart` is a window event which is not yet standardized,
So replace `document` with `window`.

Comment: Hmmm...  This creates a `ReferenceError "document is not defined"` when the `created` function is run during server-side render.  Same for `window`.  What's the strategy for `document` in Nuxt?

Comment: Link edited https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/&hl=en-IN

Comment: @MichaelCole you need to use the `mounted` hook, `created` is also executed on the server (without window/document)

Comment: @FabianvonEllerts is correct. I'd also add that when the "created" hook runs Vue doesn't guarantee that the DOM has been fully rendered, and thus all html Nodes may not be ready.